# How to highlight text in HTML without onclick

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, servlets, highlight

I would like to know how to hightlight a text variable passed from jsp or serlevt in a jsp webpage.
I dont want to use onclick to call a javascript, is there any way i can enter that page and then that texts in webpage are already hightlighted with yellow color.

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you can use onload to highlight the text :)

You could try something like `window.onload=func1;`

```
function func1() {
  document.getElementById("yourtext").style.backgroundColor="#f3f3f3";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider using css background-color property on a specific class for your object? or maybe just inline as you pass the object to html.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-color.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can add a specific class or Id to the text and then style it however you'd like

```
 <span id="mytext">this is what you want to style</span>
```

then in your css

```
#mytext{color:yellow;}
```

With a class

```
 <span class="mytext">this is what you want to style</span>
 <span class="mytext">this is what you want to style</span>
 <span class="mytext">this is what you want to style</span>
```

then in your css

```
.mytext{color:yellow;}  // this will apply to all span with the class mytext
```